# The entry MySqlProfileProvider has already been added web.config error asp

Tags: asp.net

I have recently added mysql to visual studio and have encountered this error when trying to run pages.
I have tried the `clear` command before after the opening `connectionstrings` and cant seem to find out what the problem is:

Here is my web.config in its currently state:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>        
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <clear/>
    <add name="DefaultConnection1" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-ComputingProjectwh-20170404101246.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-ComputingProjectwh-20170404101246;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <remove name="LocalMySqlServer" />
    <add name="LocalMySqlServer" connectionString="" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <membership defaultProvider="MySQLMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <remove name="MySQLMembershipProvider" />
        <add name="MySQLMembershipProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" applicationName="/" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Clear" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" />
        <add name="MySQLMembershipProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" applicationName="/" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Clear" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" /></providers>
    </membership>
    <profile defaultProvider="MySQLProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
      <remove name="MySQLProfileProvider" />
      <add name="MySQLProfileProvider" type="MySql.Web.Profile.MySQLProfileProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" applicationName="/" />
      <add name="MySQLProfileProvider" type="MySql.Web.Profile.MySQLProfileProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" applicationName="/" /></providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="MySQLRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
      <remove name="MySQLRoleProvider" />
      <add name="MySQLRoleProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLRoleProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" applicationName="/" />
      <add name="MySQLRoleProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLRoleProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" applicationName="/" /></providers>
    </roleManager>       
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
  <siteMap defaultProvider="MySqlSiteMapProvider">
      <providers>
        <remove name="MySqlSiteMapProvider" />
        <add name="MySqlSiteMapProvider" type="MySql.Web.SiteMap.MySqlSiteMapProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </siteMap><webParts>
      <personalization defaultProvider="MySQLPersonalizationProvider">
        <providers>
          <remove name="MySQLPersonalizationProvider" />
          <add name="MySQLPersonalizationProvider" type="MySql.Web.Personalization.MySqlPersonalizationProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" applicationName="/" />
        </providers>
      </personalization>
    </webParts>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.8.3.0" newVersion="6.8.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider></providers>
  </entityFramework>
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" name="MySQL Data Provider" />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" /></DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>
```

here is the error i am getting:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning     C:\Users\danie\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ComputingProjectwh\ComputingProjectwh\RevisionPages\Revision Pages List.aspx: ASP.NET runtime error: The entry 'MySQLProfileProvider' has already been added. (C:\Users\danie\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ComputingProjectwh\ComputingProjectwh\web.config line 43)  ComputingProjectwh  C:\Users\danie\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ComputingProjectwh\ComputingProjectwh\RevisionPages\Revision Pages List.aspx   1
```

Comment: You need to put the exact error message in the question itself. You're asking a lot of questions over the past few days, and I feel like you're rushing to ask rather than putting the time and thought into making sure you're putting enough detail into your questions for someone not familiar with your project to understand. Slow down, think it through, imagine how an outside will view your question. And remove anything from your configuration that's not relevant to the issue. See [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i dont know what isnt relevant

Comment: Really? You can't look at your configuration and see that certain items like comments and `Newtonsoft.Json` binding redirects have nothing to do with your issue? The more you have, the more difficult it is to spot something that would be otherwise obviosl. Like at the very bottom how you register the My SQL Data Provider twice.

Comment: No, do not put the error message in the comments. It belongs *in the question*.

Comment: apologies guys.

Comment: ive added the error and ammended the presentation of the web.config

Comment: You have more than one entry for `MySQLProfileProvider` and `MySQLMembershipProvider`. You need to remove one from each and it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You registered the DbProviderFactory for MySQL twice, with different versions. You just need one, with the latest version presumably.

```
<DbProviderFactories>
    <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" name="MySQL Data Provider" />
    <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
</DbProviderFactories>
```

Should be:

```
<DbProviderFactories>
    <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" name="MySQL Data Provider" />
    <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
</DbProviderFactories>
```

Binding redirects should take care of pointing older versions to the latest version, though you should examine all projects involved and make sure they're referencing the latest version, then you can remove the binding redirects.

Same thing for the profile provider. And there's no need for a remove statement if you clear the providers. You have:

```
<profile defaultProvider="MySQLProfileProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <remove name="MySQLProfileProvider" />
    <add name="MySQLProfileProvider" type="MySql.Web.Profile.MySQLProfileProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" applicationName="/" />
    <add name="MySQLProfileProvider" type="MySql.Web.Profile.MySQLProfileProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</profile>
```

It should be:

```
<profile defaultProvider="MySQLProfileProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="MySQLProfileProvider" type="MySql.Web.Profile.MySQLProfileProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</profile>
```

Follow this general practice of removing all the providers that have been registered more than once.

Comment: Thankyou for the responce, i am still getting the same error reffereing to this line      <remove name="MySQLRoleProvider" /><add name="MySQLRoleProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLRoleProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" applicationName="/" /><add name="MySQLRoleProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLRoleProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" applicationName="/" /></providers>

Comment: @DanielTurville Look at my answer again, I may have updated it since you last looked.

Comment: @DanielTurville you need to look for every provider and see if they are declared more than once in the file. If yes, you need to remove one.

Comment: i have changed the errors however i am still getting an error with line 49, the one above. i will post line 49 into my question

Comment: @DanielTurville You need to do what I explained in my answer *everywhere* you have registered the same provider more than once.